# Check existence of variable in webpage via content scrips

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to conditionally insert few javascript files inside the DOM of the webpage. I also want to add a dependency.

```
var load = function(filename, callback) {
   fileref  = document.createElement("script")
   fileref.setAttribute "type", "text/javascript"
   fileref.setAttribute "src", filename
   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild fileref
   if (typeof callback !== "undefined" && callback !== null) {
     callback();
   }
}

load("http://www.myserver.com/lib.js",
  function() { load("http://www.myserver.com/core.js") }
)
```

But I want to check whether the 'lib.js' is actually executed. For that, I would want to wait till a variable inside lib.js is available. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't run your `callback` immediately. Because content scripts share the DOM with their page, you can wait for the `load` event on the DOM `<script>` element:

```
var load = function(filename, callback) {
   fileref  = document.createElement("script");
   fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
   fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);

   // fire callback when script loads
   fileref.addEventListener("load", function() {
       if (typeof callback !== "undefined" && callback !== null) {
         callback();
       }
   });

   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
}

load("http://www.myserver.com/lib.js",
  // this callback will run only after lib.js has fully loaded
  function() { load("http://www.myserver.com/core.js") }
)
```

Comment: Will load event ensure the execution of the script?

Comment: @Alagu Yes, `load` events for `<script>` elements only fire after the script runs.